# MySQL Attendance System , Problems with joining tables, duplicate id's for 1 primary key

Tags: mysql

Ok So I am creating a Attendance System for a College and I am having trouble doing the tables in MySQL

The Problem I'm having is Grouping a group of students together for one class. So in MySQL

TABLE NAME: **CourseGroup:** courseGroup_id , student_id(FK), course_id(FK)

I want a number of students belonging to one class, this in hindsight will enable a teacher to undertake a register for that class group

In MySQL I have set the 'courseGroup_id as a unique field, however when I try to link  'courseGroup_id' in the Attendance table it only enables me to select 'student_id' and 'course_id'

Is it possible to select the courseGroup_id and display students for one class

My Attendance table looks like this:
Attendance: week_number, day, time, courseGroup_id, present

I want to be able to view all the students that belong to one class

Answer (score 0):

I’m a bit lost with your terminology, you speak of “class id” but don’t reefer to that in your question – instead you use “course”.

I think the best option you can do here is create another table enabling a many to many relationship as many students can be registered to one or many courses.  This type of table will enable a mapping between students and courses.

For example, if you create the mapping table “student_courses” with

```
student_id INT
course_id INT
```

You can then select students by course (joining the student table)

```
SELECT * from student_courses sc
INNER JOIN students s
  ON s.student_id = sc.srudent_id
WHERE sc.course_id = ?CourseId
```

You can also reverse it and show the courses by for an individual course:

```
SELECT * from student_courses sc
INNER JOIN courses cs
  ON cs.courset _id = sc.course_id
WHERE sc.student_id = ?StudentId
```

It is also worth pointing out that there should be two index on the student_courses, indexing both student_id and course_id for performance reasons.

Comment: Ok so I have created a table student_courses (which contains student_id(FK) & courses_id(FK) How would I , in MySQL show the group of students studying a course , as this group of students is going to be used for attendance  (Sorry about my terminology above, i confuse myself sometimes)

Comment: The first query I gave above should show the students that are enrolled on a course